# Exclude function from homepage only?

Tags: theme-development, homepage, get-template-part

There is a function in a theme that I am using that does some pagination stuff.  I do NOT want that function to show up on my home page (only), so I'm trying to set up an if/else statement but can't for the life of me can't get it to work right.  Using the following code, the function shows up not only on the homepage but also on the category pages.  I am using this code in my index.php file and my site is setup to show posts from a custom post type.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div>My Loop Stuff Here</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php if (!( is_home() || is_front_page() )) : function_to_NOT_show_on_homepage(); endif; ?>

<?php else: ?>
    [else stuffs]
<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your pastes, i think what you're going for is..

```
function cp_do_pagination() {   

    if( is_home() || is_singular() /* || is_front_page() */ )
        return;

    global $post; // <-- do you need this for something in particular?

    if( !function_exists('appthemes_pagination') )
        return;

    appthemes_pagination();
}
```

The `is_singular()` function covers `is_page()`, `is_single()` and `is_attachment()`, so no need for the additional conditionals.

Info on that function here, for reference.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular

Comment: *face palm* clearly my statement was false with regard to `is_singular`, either the function has changed or i misunderstood it's usage to begin with, `is_singular` does in fact compare against a post type or post types... (i really should read the page i'm linking to)...

Comment: Thanks t3los, but that doesn't work either.  It shows up on the blog pages and the custom post pages, but it also shows up on the homepage, which is what I am trying to remove it from.

Comment: Ok! :)  So.... what if we change it to is_home?

Comment: BTW this whole pagination situation (ha ha) from this theme is really ticking me off...

Comment: Whoops, forgot the `is_home` condition, adjusted the code sample.

Comment: Well it's halfway there.  That seems to work but I have multiple loops on my index.php (homepage), and it only is removing the pagination function from the first loop.

Comment: Could you pastebin the index.php in it's entirety?

Comment: @t3los here you go: http://pastebin.com/6v2FwTvA

Answer (score 0):

i think you need `<?php if (is_home()) { ?>` this worked for me i dont think is_front_page is required

Comment: If I use is_home, it echos only on the homepage and nowhere else.  I want the opposite of that.

Comment: Did you try adding is_home to your function?

Comment: I tried adding the conditional statement around the function itself, as well as in my index page around the CALL to the function, but neither seem to work.

Comment: please post your function

Comment: http://pastebin.com/KgV6NJMd and the second function included in that one is here http://pastebin.com/KJd9GWiQ

Comment: http://pastebin.com/m7mAZb8Q
one of these should work

Comment: Yes, you *do* need `is_front_page()`. The `is_home()` conditional applies to the **Blog Posts Index**, whether displayed on the **Site Front Page** or not. For the **Site Front Page**, use `is_front_page()`. (Note that, unless you're using a static Page as the Site Front Page, it won't matter as the two conditionals will both return true.)

Comment: @Jeremy Love - The first function removed the pagination from the homepage but it ALSO removed it from the custom post type pages as well, which is not what I wanted to do.  The second function didn't work at all, and I had already tried that, as well as wrapping all of that around the outer function.

Comment: @Chip - If the homepage runs thru a custom query that displays only posts from a certain custom post type (let's say "books"), would that make a difference in this case?  My WP Reading Settings are set to "use latest posts"...

Comment: @RodeoRamsey if you're using a custom query to output custom posts, I would strongly consider using a static Page as your Front Page, so that you're not impacting your Blog Posts Index. Regardless, I don't think the rules for `is_front_page()` and `is_home()` would be impacted, since the default query is run long before your custom query at the Loop.

Comment: Thanks Chip - I agree, because changing the settings in the dashboard DO affect the homepage.  I can't change TOO much on this theme because it's a complete theme changing WP into a classified ads site and I don't want to trip the logic on the rest of the theme.